# python used sshtunnel can't connect to mysql

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to use `sshtunnel` and `MySQLdb` in `python2.7` to tunnel my connection and facing following problem:

I used Sequel Pro to connect mysql was OK, but the python code did not work!

Sequel Pro is like this:

[connect info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1pnU.png)

and code is like this:

```
`from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
import MySQLdb
with SSHTunnelForwarder(
        ('2.2.2.2', 22),
        ssh_username='name2',
        ssh_password='mypassword',
        remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3306)
) as tunnel:
    connection = MySQLdb.connect(
    user='name1',
    password='mypassword',
    host='1.1.1.1',
    database='mydata',
    port=3306)
```

I searched some example code like:

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
import MySQLdb

with SSHTunnelForwarder(
        (_host, _ssh_port),
        ssh_username=_username,
        ssh_password=_password,
        remote_bind_address=(_remote_bind_address, _remote_mysql_port),
        local_bind_address=(_local_bind_address, _local_mysql_port)
) as tunnel:
    connection = MySQLdb.connect(
    user=_db_user,
    password=_db_password,
    host=_local_bind_address,
    database=_db_name,
    port=_local_mysql_port)
```

I want to know that did I do the right way to built ssh or connect to mysql? Thanks for help!

**update:**
the error message:

```
2017-06-15 17:52:58,415| ERROR   | Could not connect to gateway 1.1.1.1:22 : 110
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sshtunnel.py", line 1483, in __enter__
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sshtunnel.py", line 1225, in start
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sshtunnel.py", line 1037, in _raise
sshtunnel.BaseSSHTunnelForwarderError: Could not establish session to SSH gateway
```

Answer (score 2):

Update your code to add the local_bind_address:

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
import MySQLdb
with SSHTunnelForwarder(
        ('2.2.2.2', 22),
        ssh_username='name2',
        ssh_password='mypassword',
        remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3306),
        local_bind_address = ('1.1.1.1', 3306)
) as tunnel:
    connection = MySQLdb.connect(
    user='name1',
    password='mypassword',
    host='1.1.1.1',
    database='mydata',
    port=3306)
```

Unless you specify your Localhost (as '1.1.1.1' in your case) & Port; MYSQL service will not be available for the localhost.
I Hope this helps.